# python write a list of lists to multiple columns in excel(not in rows)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write many columns in excel. Trying to enter a `record` to columns.
I have a list let's say as below

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

the other list will be like

```
list2=['a','b','c']
```

I will have many different sized(length) lists which is why I cannot create `dataframe` in pandas and write it.

```
list3=['1a','2b','3c','4d']
```

I want it in excel be like

[image]

I am not sure which framework to use, `openpyxl` or `pandas` which will solve this issue

EDIT for user @Timeless

I have used your suggestion in this way;

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(var_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='r+', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    book = load_workbook(var_path)
    current_sheet = book[var_sheetname]
    Column_H = current_sheet['H']
    try:
        maxrow = max(c.row for c in Column_H if c.value is not None)
    except ValueError:
        maxrow = 1

    print(var_sheetname,maxrow,'writing docs')
    var_inp.to_excel(writer,startrow=maxrow,startcol=Column_H,sheet_name=var_sheetname,index=False,header=False)
```

Comment: Pandas would be using openpyxl (or xlsxwriter, or some other engine depending on the file format) under the hood anyway to actually create the Excel file.

Comment: with pandas problem is I have no exact column names, but I want to insert a list as a record. Pandas is obliged to have column names(as keys in dictiory) for writing many rows.

Comment: To write the three lists just use Openpyxl `append` It will append a list to the next unused row in the sheet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the library documentation explains exactly how to do this.

Comment: please read carefullt, it writes multiple columns on one row. That's why I needed list of lists in a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a *nested list* :

```
L = [list1, list2, list3]
```

Then you can use [`Worksheet.append`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for sub_list in L:
    ws.append(sub_list)

wb.save("book1.xlsx")
```

Or with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(L).to_excel("book2.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Output (*spreadsheet*) :

[image]

Comment: I am having `raise KeyError("passes columns are not ALL present dataframe")
KeyError: 'passes columns are not ALL present dataframe'` when using pandas

Comment: So you're getting an error when using your inputs in the question + my code ? I don't think it's possible. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I have edited question, added my code snippet, could you please look at it. I guess it is unknown length of list and I use `columns` in writer only `column H`. meaning start to add data from column H ->  multiple columns